# How to read 2 MongoDB collections with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, request

I would like to know if it is possible to read several collections of the same mongoDB database in JavaScript.

Here is my fonctionnal mongoDB query:

```
db.accounts.find({
    $and: [
    {
        createD: { $lt: ISODate("2017-01-01") }
    },
    {
        createD: { $gte: ISODate("2015-12-31") }
    }
]}).forEach((account) => {
    var idProfilFromAccount = account.profils.forEach((profil)=>{
        var unikProfil = db.profils.distinct("unik", {_id:ObjectId(profil)}).toString();
        console.log("ID ACCOUNT : " + account._id + " | UNIK PROFIL : " + unikProfil);
    });
});
```

To be more precise, I would like to read the data of a table with a parameter coming from another table.

I tried several solutions but without much success.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Could you show the data from both collections and expected output ?

Comment: In the Accounts collection, I have an array of profils containing differents profils ids. I want to go into the collection of profils to get the data "UNIK" via the id of the profils which is in the table of the profils of the Accounts collection.
In output, I wish to have the id of the account as well as the unik of the associated profile (if several profiles, the id account appears several times)

My mongoDB request as it is above works, I can not find the way to transcribe it in javascript.

Comment: Take a look at $lookup, might be helpful in this scenario: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html

Comment: The fact is that I get what i want with the request i put in my question. I'm now using a nodejs server (with Hapi) and I don't now how to read two collections in one request. I already looked at lookup, but without any success. 
Maybe a should try to make two diffrents requests.

Comment: So please show your efforts with $lookup, it's the only one to fetch the data from multiple collections in one round trip